# How to build a facebook-like activity stream sidebar in Django?

Tags: django

I've been looking for this across the web and I've found some interesting approaches like **Djando Activity Stream**, but I want to develop my own application based on what is already done. **What I specifically want is to know how to approach on developing a Facebook-like side bar** that displays a activity stream based on actors, actions, objects and time. What is the most flexible database schema? How to implement it with an existing contacts application? How to make it personalized for every user? how to group related activities? Is it javascript the best way to handle the client side control?

I'm currently working with contentTypes and GenericRelations to be able to relate different application models. But I'm still not on track with this. Your help, tips and comments about how to develop this in the simplest and more flexible way will be very helpful.

Comment: Google `real-time Django`? As simple as long pulling will do it...I am not sure whether they use HTML5 websocket... There is a library called `socket.IO`. In any case, just google real time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right package to use: [django-notification](http://django-notification.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) Secondly you just use plain old jQuery and ajax calls to put the stream of request.user in the sidebar. you could also filter the action stream based on actor, object or something else.